# How can I count iterations with NestWhile?

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration, infinite-loop

I'd like to count loop iterations for some substitution rules.
For example:

```
rule = {1 -> {0}, 0 -> {1}}  
init = {0}  
maxIter = 10
```

I'm going to avoid all intermediate results, so I used `NestWhile`. But I need to know how many iterations happened, so I tried to use a counter and `UnsameQ`.

```
NestWhile[{#[[1]] + 1, SubstitutionSystem[rule, #[[2]]]} &, {1, init}, 
 UnsameQ[#[[2]]] &, All, maxIter]
```

But this is not work. What test I should I apply to count iterations of the loop?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your expected output?

Comment: @lericr  Some clarification added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I get it now. Let's start without the counter, and let's use `NestWhileList` for clarity:

```
NestWhileList[
  SubstitutionSystem[rule, #] &,
  init,
  Not[MemberQ[Most[{##}], Last[{##}]]] &,
  All,
  maxIter]

(* {{0},{1},{0}} *)
```

Now let's try to add in the counter:

```
NestWhileList[
  {#[[1]] + 1, SubstitutionSystem[rule, #[[2]]]} &,
  {1, init},
  Not[MemberQ[Most[{##}][[All, 2]], Last[{##}][[2]]]] &,
  All,
  maxIter]

(* {{1, {0}}, {2, {1}}, {3, {0}}} *)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, idea with `##` helps me in a similar problem!